# Play Framework Scala: Run "test" before "run" in the triggered execution mode

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

Everytime I change code in the project I would like to run two separate sbt actions in this order:

1. test
2. run

I thought it is possible with activator/sbt commands like `~ ; test ; run`, but it sticks to "run" and don't do any testing until I break sequence with Ctrl-D.

Is this possible to run "test" action before "run" in triggered execution mode?

Comment: Open two SBT sessions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the nature of `run` it won't re-run `test` on a code change. What perhaps might work for you is to have 2 sbt shells open, one with `~test` and one with `~run`.

A note of warning though, multiple sbt shells, especially in trigger execution, *can* trip over itself because there's limited locking on the relevant files - which is one of the things sbt server hopes to solve.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, Dale. Looks like two sbt sessions is the best thing Play can offer.